# In sqlalchemy, how can I use polymorphic joined table inheritance when the child table has multiple foreign keys to the parent table?

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I have a parent table called `pbx_point` that has a `point_type` column. I also have a child table called `pbx_route`, with a column called `point_id` pointing back to `pbx_point`.

I'd like to use sqlalchemy's joined table inheritance to relate these two tables via declarative base, and use polymorphic inheritance

This works fine - or rather, it would, if not for the following additional constraint: `pbx_point` also has a foreign key called `initial_route_id` pointing to `pbx_route`.

I'm also using reflection below, but the db is as I described above. The error I get is `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'pbx_point' and 'pbx_route'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.`.

This makes sense, as "behind the scenes" delcarative base is creating a relationship() attribute on both mapped classes. I'd like it to choose `pbx_route.point_id` as the parent_id link, but it also sees the `pbx_point.initial_route_id` column. This would be simple to fix, if I was creating this relationship(), but I am not - the declarative inheritance system is.

Is there an additional argument I can pass to `__mapper_args__`, such as `polymorphic_parent_col` which would let me specify the foreign key I desire? If not, how can I work around this issue?

Thanks.

```
class MyBase(DeferredReflection):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

Base = declarative_base(cls=MyBase)

class pbx_point(Base):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(
        polymorphic_on='point_type',
        with_polymorphic='*',
    )

class pbx_route(pbx_point):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity='pbx.route')
```

This is the stack trace I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 50, in <module>
    Base.prepare(engine)
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 431, in prepare
    thingy.map()
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 379, in map
    **mapper_args
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/__init__.py", line 1147, in mapper
    return Mapper(class_, local_table, *args, **params)
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 213, in __init__
    self._configure_inheritance()
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 517, in _configure_inheritance
    self.local_table)
  File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 397, in join_condition
    "join explicitly." % (a.description, b.description))
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'pbx_point' and 'pbx_route'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

Which indicates it is dying at [line 1032 in mapper.py](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_3_11/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py#L1032)*. A few lines above that makes reference to the mapper kwarg `inherit_condition` , which appears to be what I need.

[*]: Source link adjusted to version 1.3.11 (previous URL now 404s)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key is the [`inherit_condition`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.inherit_condition) argument to the mapper. The polymorphic information doesn't actually have anything to do with this step.

Corrected models:

```
class MyBase(DeferredReflection):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

Base = declarative_base(cls=MyBase)

class pbx_point(Base):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(
        polymorphic_on='point_type',
        with_polymorphic='*',
    )
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class pbx_route(pbx_point):
    point_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(pbx_point.id))
    __mapper_args__ = dict(
        polymorphic_identity='pbx.route',
        inherit_condition=(point_id == pbx_point.id)
    )
```

I needed to add the `id` and `point_id` columns to use them in the `inherit_condition` argument. There is likely to be a way to do this only using reflection, but this is not a terrible hindrance.

Comment: I had this exact problem and could NOT find it in the docs. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thank you. The documentation is extensive. I couldn't find at first. Here's the link  for the curious: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.inherit_condition